# How to differentiate the subtle differences among these glittering words?

Tags: difference

> “Your gorilla hearts are made of ice, Ivan,” she said, her eyes **glittering**.

I read this sentence in *The One and Only Ivan* which is a children's book.

According to Google dictionary, `glitter` in this context means that **shine with a bright, shimmering reflected light**.

But I found these words mean almost the same:

- shine
- sparkle
- twinkle
- glint
- gleam
- shimmer
- glimmer

How to differentiate the subtle differences among these glittering words?

Do I have to memorize the meaning of every word? Is there a better way?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure that I agree with Oxford's use of _shimmering_ here; I prefer Cambridge's definition _to shine with little, bright flashes of reflected light_. _Shimmering_ is a soft reflected light, like satin or a calm sea on a fine evening.

Comment: "Shine", "Shimmer", "glimmer" etc. are **not** vocabularies.  They are *words*.  A vocabulary is the collection of all the words that a person knows.  You can say "Joe has a large vocabulary". It means "Joe knows lots of words"

Comment: @JamesK Thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a native speaker of English, I could barely distinguish the meanings of those words. For instance, I could suggest:

- **gleam** has a sense of a diffuse light, like light through frosted glass
- **twinkle** has a sense that the light is constantly varying slightly (like stars)
- **glint** has a sense that light briefly bounced off the object, but is not constant. Metaphorically it often seems to mean an idea expressed in someone's eyes.
- **sparkle** if the light is particularly bright, with a sense of movement and a very specific point (like Christmas tree lights), often has a metaphorical sense of cheeriness
- **shimmer** often seems to have a sense of a broad areas of light moving across a surface, like moonlight catching waves on a lake
- **glimmer**? no idea, much the same as "gleam" to me.
- **glitter** sounds archaic to me as a verb, for me it's tiny pieces of foil that stick to you

I don't know a better way than reading a lot, to be honest. Most of the associations and understanding I have of these words are just from reading them in books and hearing them in songs. The words that I would actually use, with distinct meanings, in my day to day life are probably "shine", "sparkle", "glint" (particularly describing light catching a piece of metal in a way that catches your eye) and maybe "shimmer".

> Do I have to memorize the meaning of every word?

Depends on your goals, I suppose. In terms of passive understanding, I don't think you're missing much by treating them all as "light catching an object".